# How to take variables from another Makefile in shell script

Tags: shell-script, arch-linux, kernel-modules, make

I want to use the variables from another Makefile under the directory `~/kernelbuild/linux-3.14.37` in my own shell script.

Following is the variables that I need:

```
VERSION = 3
PATCHLEVEL = 14
SUBLEVEL = 37
```

**The problem is that I am not allowed to change the Makefile**, so export variable is not an option here.

Also, I have seen people saying to have a separate file that contains all the common variables need. **This is practical but I need to put everything just in my single shell script**.

I tried to include `. ~/kernelbuild/linux-3.14.37/Makefile` in my shell script and I thought I should be able to use those variables, but it gives me following errors:

```
/home/jl4347/kernelbuild/linux-3.14.37/Makefile: line 1: VERSION: command not found
/home/jl4347/kernelbuild/linux-3.14.37/Makefile: line 2: PATCHLEVEL: command not found
/home/jl4347/kernelbuild/linux-3.14.37/Makefile: line 3: SUBLEVEL: command not found
/home/jl4347/kernelbuild/linux-3.14.37/Makefile: line 4: EXTRAVERSION: command not found
/home/jl4347/kernelbuild/linux-3.14.37/Makefile: line 5: NAME: command not found
/home/jl4347/kernelbuild/linux-3.14.37/Makefile: line 17: MAKEFLAGS: command not found
/home/jl4347/kernelbuild/linux-3.14.37/Makefile: line 20: unexport: command not found
/home/jl4347/kernelbuild/linux-3.14.37/Makefile: line 26: unexport: command not found
/home/jl4347/kernelbuild/linux-3.14.37/Makefile: line 47: syntax error near unexpected token `"$(origin V)",'
/home/jl4347/kernelbuild/linux-3.14.37/Makefile: line 47: `ifeq ("$(origin V)", "command line")'
```

I think that's because the Makefile is not following the syntax rules for shell script. How can I do that then?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to extract the values with grep and sed. For example:

```
filename="$HOME/kernelbuild/linux-3.14.37/Makefile"
version=$(grep -m 1 VERSION $filename | sed 's/^.*= //g')
```

This greps for first occurrence of "VERSION" in Makefile

Comment: I tried your way, but it gives error like `grep: ~/kernelbuild/linux-3.14.37/Makefile: No such file or directory`, and I am sure I use the right path. Why is that?

Comment: Sorry, tilde is not expanded when quoted. You can substitute it with $HOME variable or expand to full path. I corrected my answer.

Answer (score 5):

If you need just simple things like your example, just `grep` them out of the Makefile.

For more complicated things, GNU Make has a `-p` option which prints the database after running Make, which includes all the variable definitions (and a lot more). You can use it together with `-n`, which causes the actions to not actually run (so nothing gets built). You can `grep` the variables out of the `-p` output.

Answer (score 3):

Make can read a makefile from stdin, so you can give it a *here document* that is a makefile. The following is a makefile that includes your kernel makefile and adds a new wildcard target, `%.var`, whose recipe will output the value of the given make variable. (This assumes you don't have any files or other targets that end in `.var`, of course).

```
showvar() {
make -f - ${1}.var <<'EOF'
include $(HOME)/kernelbuild/linux-3.14.37/Makefile

%.var:
    @echo $($*)
EOF
}

my_version=$(showvar VERSION)
patchlevel=$(showvar PATCHLEVEL)
the_sublevel=$(showvar SUBLEVEL)
```

Make will replace `$*` with the stem of the `%.var` target.

The `@echo` recipe line begins with an actual <kbd>TAB</kbd> character.